# Using Apache HTTP in Android 9

Tags: android

I have problem with on Android 9:

```
org.apache.http.HttpEntity org.apache.http.HttpResponse.getEntity()
```

This is because the SDK does not support this

Addition

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

or

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

does not solve the problem

I have a different question in this situation:

Can I do it like on the code below?

`compileSdkVersion` I have **28** but `targetSdkVersion` **26**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myApp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

In this arrangement the application will work

I emphasize that the application is very simple and does not use anything from the new version of the SDK

What are the risks of such a solution, what is the threat, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: I have a lot of code written and I need to adapt the application to Android 9 in a simple and fast way